# Is there a javascript library to put a CAD-like widget on a website?

Tags: javascript, modeling, 3d

I want users to be able to draw very simple 3D drawings (but with precise measurements) on my website. For example, they could create a 3D model of their house.

Is there a javascript library with this functionality?